# MySQL query to duplicate a meta_key from wp_postmeta into a new meta_key

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Basically I want to uninstall Yoast SEO because it adds 7 seconds to my site's load time, but i want to keep the focus keywords for seo purposes.

But first i would like to copy the focus keywords into my own 'focus' post meta.

The structure is like this in red, and i would like it to add the part in green. Afterwards i will remove all Yoast's references:

[image: DB structure]

- Yoast's meta_key:  _yoast_wpseo_focuskw
- Desired key to copy to: focus

I am not so clued up with sql queries, but i've tried:

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET _yoast_wpseo_focuskw = focus

But it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_key = 'focus' WHERE  meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw'
```